# VS 2017 + Xamarin: Imported project was not found

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When I try to create a Xamarin.Fomrs project in Visual Studio 2017, it keeps giving me the following error:

[image]

I have tried to re-install VS, but that didn't work. When I open the project in File Explorer, everything is there. However, when I open the solution in Solution Explorer in VS, it says 0 projects, why? How can I fix this?

EDIT:
The files `.projitems` and `.csproj` do exist, when I open the path in File Explorer, so I don't understand the error

Comment: Refer to : https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/issues/1752

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT: I can't see how that should help me fix it? :) I have a different issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed the problem. The issue was that when I created the project, I typed a projectname with spaces. Replacing them with `_` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I had a similar issue that you helped resolve.  I created a new project that had a hyphen "-" in the game and got the above error.  The project would create but it wouldn't load.  I didn't use an underscore, I just crammed the letters together.  But it let me create the project.